# JavaScript infinite scroll with intersection observer

Tags: javascript, html

I built a simple infinite scroll using the intersection observer API, would love some feedback on ways to improve my JavaScript and make it more maintainable and reusable, and feedback according to best JavaScript practices.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Infinite Scroll</title>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
      }
      .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        max-width: 520px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 1rem 2rem;
      }
      #load-more {
        padding: 1rem 2rem;
        margin: 2;
        background-color: darkcyan;
        color: white;
        border-radius: 1rem;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="infinite-scroll-imgs-container"></div>
      <div id="load-more">Loading more content...</div>
    </div>
    <script>
      const loadMore = document.querySelector("#load-more");
      const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersect, { threshold: 1 });
      const imgsContainer = document.querySelector("#infinite-scroll-imgs-container");

      observer.observe(loadMore)

      function randomInteger() {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
      }

      function imgGenerator(images) {
        const imgs = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < images; i += 1) {
          const img = document.createElement("img");
          img.src = `http://api.adorable.io/avatars/${randomInteger()}`;
          img.classList.add('infinite-scroll-img')
          imgs.push(img);
        }
        return imgs;
      }

      function appendImages(container, images) {
        container.append(...imgGenerator(images));
      }

      function handleIntersect(entries, observer) {
        entries.forEach((entry) => {
          if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            appendImages(imgsContainer, 5);
          }
        });
      }

      appendImages(imgsContainer, 5);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `container` and `images` are being repeated unecessarly.

---

When you call `imgGenerator` in `appendImages`, you already know that you want an array of images.

You can use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

- the first argument will be an `array-like` object, that is, an object that is accessed by index and with a length propertie(which is identified as `images` on our javascript)
- the second argument will be the `mapFunction`(which will
  be `imgGenerator`), a function that will be called for every
  item of the array

Doing this, on `imgGenerator` you avoid to make an instance of an array(`imgs`), a push into it and a `for` loop every time you want this array, although, you will not need to pass `images` as parameter again

---

the `container` is always `imgsContainer`, so, in the `appendImages` you already know where to append

```js
function imgGenerator() {
  const img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = `http://api.adorable.io/avatars/${randomInteger()}`;
  img.classList.add('infinite-scroll-img');
  return img;
}

function appendImages(images) {
  imgsContainer.append(
    ...Array.from({ length: images }, imgGenerator)
  );
}

function handleIntersect(entries) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      appendImages(5);
    }
  });
}

appendImages(5);
```